# JDO Exception: Identifier unresolved(Not a static fields)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

> i am making an object persistent using JDO. I have run code numerous times. At times, i get things persisted without any error. At times, i receive the following errors.
>
> 1. org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException
> 2. javax.jdo.JDOUserException
>
> I dont understand why it runs successfully sometimes and why it fails sometimes. These happens very randomly. My application is validating new User during signUp. Here goes my code.

```
> ##    User.java(entity being persisted) ##


 @Entity
 @PersistenceCapable

 public class User {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
public String userName;

@Persistent
private String name, password, city, bikeModel, age;

public User(){

}
public User(String name, String uname, String pswd, String age, String city, String bike){
    this.name=name;
    this.userName=uname;
    this.password=pswd;
    this.age=age;
    this.city=city;
    this.bikeModel=bike;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
//rest of the getters
}



    //Getting SignUp form values
    String name=req.getParameter("name1");
    String uname=req.getParameter("uname1");
    String pswd=req.getParameter("pswd1");
    String age=req.getParameter("age");
    String city=req.getParameter("city");
    String bike=req.getParameter("bike");

            //PeristenceManager instance
            PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

            //Creating instance for persistent entity class
     User newEntry=new User(name,uname,pswd,age,city,bike);

            //Query to match the userName entered in form and that of the dataStore user
    Query q = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    q.setFilter("userName == userNameParam");
    q.declareParameters("String userNameParam");
            try{
      List<User> results = (List<User>) q.execute(uname);
      if (!results.isEmpty()) {
                //if userName is found in DataStore
            resp.sendRedirect("invalidUser.html");  
      } else{
             //If userName is not found in dataStore
          pm.makePersistent(newEntry);          
          resp.sendRedirect("success.html");
          return;
      }
     }**strong text**
    finally{

        System.out.println("Finally!");
    }
```

***error logs:***

```
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Exception message : Identifier Status is unresolved (not a static field)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler: Error in class DataAccessLayer
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:519)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOQuery.executeWithArray(JDOQuery.java:321)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.datastore.DataAccessLayer.searchObjects(DataAccessLayer.java:213)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.businessaccesslayer.GLoginManager.getNewPasswordCSVs(GLoginManager.java:24202)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.backends.ReadPasswordCSVFile.doGet(ReadPasswordCSVFile.java:71)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)


 com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:50)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:504)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:446)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:453)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:276)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:312)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:304)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:450)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
com.cloudcodes.gcontrol.utility.ErrorHandler errorHandler:  
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: So you get some exception from some operation but dont say what the operation is for that exception, or what the stack trace for the exception is? Nobody can help you with those details. AppEngine uses such an old version of JDO that you're unlikely to find people who will support it any more.

Comment: i have  added FULL STACK TRACE in your QUESTION

Comment: Sadly that is not the full stack trace. e.printStackTrace gives you nested exceptions also, and the root cause exception is the one required ...